# Excel Merge Similar Rows into one row based on 3 columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

OK, So I have a spreadsheet that was made by combining two identically structured spreadsheets that merged all the data into one.  The problem is that both spreadsheets have "similar" data but one has more data than the other but both have data that is missing in each of the spreadsheets but all the data is required to be kept.  One suggestion I was given was to manually go through the spreadsheet row by row to combine the rows.  Given there are 5000 rows in this spreadsheet, this option is not desirable.  I did find a VB Script that allowed me to combine rows of similar information, the problem was it seems to only combine everything into on row based on one column of information.

```
    Sub MG30Nov12()
    'Updateby20150519
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim InputRng As Range
    Dim nRng As Range
    Set InputRng = Application.Selection
    Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set InputRng = InputRng.Parent.Range(InputRng.Columns(1).Address)
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each Rng In InputRng
        If Not .Exists(Rng.Value) Then
            .Add Rng.Value, Rng.Offset(, 1)
        Else
            .Item(Rng.Value).Value = .Item(Rng.Value).Value + Rng.Offset(, 1)
                If nRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set nRng = Rng
                Else
                    Set nRng = Union(nRng, Rng)
                End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then
        nRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

What i would like to do is do something like this but combine over multiple coulmn data.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the word:

```
Rng.Offset(, 1)
```

to

```
Rng.Offset(, 3)
```

Hope this help.